# Custom post type support for get_users('orderby=post_count');

Tags: custom-post-types, users

The default WordPress function `get_users('orderby=post_count');` only orders users with the count of the *posts* they've made.

Any idea how to modify this to support custom post types as well?

**UPDATE:**

I only want to query posts of type "company-item". Currently, this snippet is in my functions.php:

```
 function user_query_count_post_type($args) {
   $args->query_from = str_replace("post_type = post AND", "post_type IN ('company-item') AND ", $args->query_from);
  }
```

And this is in my page template:

```
<ul>
  <?php
  add_action('pre_user_query','user_query_count_post_type');
  $showrooms = get_users('orderby=post_count&role=company&order=desc');
  remove_action('pre_user_query','user_query_count_post_type');

  foreach ($showrooms as $showroom) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $showroom->id ); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $showroom->company_logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $showroom->company_name; ?>" /></a>
    </li>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to replace the where clause of the query by hooking to `pre_user_query`. Something like:

```
function user_query_count_post_type($args){
    $args->query_from = str_replace("post_type = post AND", "post_type IN ('post','cpt') AND ", $args->query_from);
}
```

Usage ex:

```
add_action('pre_user_query','user_query_count_post_type');
$users = get_users('orderby=post_count');
remove_action('pre_user_query','user_query_count_post_type');
```

Comment: Tried that, but getting the error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_User_Query as array`

Comment: @Hassan, my bad , i think i fixed it.

Comment: this still does not work. Do I need to modify anything in the code?

Comment: @Hassan  yeah you need to modify `cpt` with the name of your custom post type .

Comment: Yup, I obviously changed that since my first try, but still getting no results. What I'm doing is I've put the above code snippet in my functions.php file and then used `get_users('orderby=post_count');` normally in a page template. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You put the function in your functions.php but you call it with the rest of the snippet

Comment: I don't get it; the code looks logical but I'm still getting no result. Bainternet, have you been able to actually test this code snippet and confirm that it's indeed working?

Comment: Yes I have ,update your question with what you have tried

Comment: Updated my original question.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: I'm just getting some random ordering. Some users who have zero posts are at the top, while others with varying numbers of posts are randomly placed on the list. Also, this "random ordering" seems to be constantly changing while surfing around the site.

Comment: str_replace("post_type = post AND" ... , should be str_replace("post_type = 'post' AND " ... then it will work, note the ' around post and the space after AND

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but, just in case someone needs it on the future.
You could add a `get_posts` inside the normal `foreach` for users, to check if a given user has stuff published on posts, OR on the CPT you want:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'contributors_author_list' ) ) :

function contributors_author_list() {

    $contributor_ids = get_users( array(
        'fields'  => 'ID',
        'orderby' => 'post_count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'who'     => 'authors',
        'number' => '100'
    ) );

    foreach ( $contributor_ids as $contributor_id ) :

        $argos = array( 'author' => $contributor_id, 'post_type'=> array('post','CHANGE-HERE-YOUR-CPT') ); //change here the CPT
        $userposts = get_posts($argos);
        $count=count($userposts);
        if ($count) {
    ?>

<!-- HTML stuff -->    

    <?php    
        }
    endforeach;
}
endif;
```

This way you should be able to display authors who published either posts or Custom Post Types (or both).